# extract a file that contains lzh compression strings

Tags: python, c++, compression, lzh

I have data file(it has not extension-file type) that I think it is combination of two types of strings: one string is plain text and another one is string which has been compressed by [LZH(LHA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LHA_(file_format)) algorithm,when I open the file with notepad++ it is look like this: [image]

as it shows in picture some data is readable but other data are compressed, is there any software or  source code  in python,c++, php, or any other language that can read this file by chunk and decompressed them?
I googled but I found many source codes or software that decompress lzh,but they decomprssed a file that totally compressed by lzh, and first they check the head of file and if it is not lzh file give error.

Comment: *I think it is combination of two types of strings:* -- You should ask the person / people / company that created the file to state what the data is and how to interpret it.

Comment: the software that creates this file is old and there is no new versioni